# sum of values in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am querying a database. Then inserting the resultant values into an array and finding their sum. This is the code:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT items FROM mytable WHERE user_id='$id'");
$array=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //insert values into array
    $array=$row; 
    $sum=array_sum($row); 
    echo $sum;
}
```

This just returns the items in the array and not the sum. How do I correct that?
Ps:I had tried this here earlier, but it halves the correct result:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT items FROM mytable WHERE user_id='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM); 
$sum = array_sum($row);
echo $sum;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use `SELECT sum(items) FROM mytable WHERE userid="$id"` ?  You'll save CPU if you push this kind of thing off to the database server.

Comment: I agree - make the summation part of your query if that's all you need (i.e. if you just discard the array afterward): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT items FROM mytable WHERE user_id='$id'");
$array = array();
$sum = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  //insert values into array
  $array[] = $row; 
  $sum += $row;
}
echo $sum;
```

This would be the code if you need both the array and the respective sum. If you just need the sum, it would be much more efficient, if you have your database do the summation by turning your query into

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(items) FROM mytable WHERE user_id='$id'");
$sum = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
```

Comment: actually in the actual code i am selecting more than 1 item from the DB as follows:

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT name,quantity,price,items FROM mytable WHERE user_id='$id'");

now how do i get the sum of the 'items' form the above query using an array?

Comment: replace the `$sum += $row;` with `$sum += $row['items'];

Answer (score 0):

Using database layer usually is more faster than business logic

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(items) AS mysum FROM mytable WHERE user_id='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC); 
/* always use assoc to prevent yourself from errors after table's modification */
echo $row['mysum'];
```